# Return value of .exe using bat script in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am rather new to Jenkins. I am trying to run a `UnitTest.exe` and to check the value of the return code of it. In the JenkinsFile:

```
stage('Unit Tests')
{
    steps{
        script{
            def statusCode = bat script: "UnitTest.exe", returnStatus:true
            echo statusCode
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to see the output of the program (all the `std::cout`), but I am unable to print out the return value `statusCode`

Comment: Try `echo "$statusCode"`

Comment: You may also have to insert `exit /b %errorlevel%` at end of batch script.

Answer (score 0):

as @zett42 said,
instead of using `echo statusCode` using

```
echo "$statusCode"
```

instead should do the trick

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).